# Regression expression for password field in Angular2

Tags: regex, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create user registration form in Angular using Reactive forms.
I want password validation like it should start with a capital letter, to have at least one number, at least one special character, and no restriction for small letters.

What I have is:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {


    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({ //root group [formGroup]
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        password: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(25), Validators.pattern('')]],
```

// **Validators.pattern(''**)

here i need to use the regression expression but I do not know which will be the right one for my requirements above

```
        emailGroup: this.fb.group({   
            email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+")]],
            confirmEmail: ['', Validators.required],
        }, { validator: emailMatcher }),
        country: [null, [Validators.required]],



    })

    let getNotification = this.customerForm.get('notification')
    getNotification.valueChanges
        .subscribe(value => this.sentNotification(value)) //subscribe is like a for each so it displays the output

    const emailControl = this.customerForm.get('emailGroup.email');
    emailControl.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .subscribe(value =>
            this.setMessageForEmail(emailControl));

    const firstNameControl = this.customerForm.get('firstName')
    firstNameControl.valueChanges              
        .subscribe(value =>
            this.setMessageForFirstName(firstNameControl))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you're looking for is

```
[A-Z](?=.*\d)(?=.*[---ALL YOUR SPECIAL CHARS HERE])(?=.*[a-z])
```

Or close to that. It uses [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find your special char and your number

Comment: You need to use `*` instead of `{1}` in the lookaheads. Otherwise it is a no-op - every token is matched exactly once unless specified otherwise, so you can always drop it.